# "read_imageui" can't get the correct data(using OpenCV + OpenCL)

Tags: c++, opencv, opencl, gpu, gpgpu

I used OpenCV to read and show image, and OpenCL for image processing.
In the past several months, the cl_mem format I used is buffer.
And now I'm test the OpenCL image format. But I had some problems in a simple code. I got nothing after using read_imageui(the results are 0 always).

The code is very simple. I read one image using OpenCV, then transform the data into OpenCL image, then I use a buffer to read data. Finally I copied it to the host again. I ignored some OpenCL Initialization codes to make it more clear.

Here I have one more question, if I use one gray image(one channel), then the OpenCL image format is CL_A/ CL_R right? And if I use one unsigned char in OpenCV, is the OpenCL format is CL_UNSIGNED_INT8? I knew cl_int8 is 32 byte. But cl_uchar is 1 byte. I'm confused.

Thank you!

```
//////DEVICE test.cl //////////////////////////
__constant sampler_t sampler_test = 
CLK_NORMALIZED_COORDS_FALSE | CLK_ADDRESS_CLAMP_TO_EDGE | CLK_FILTER_NEAREST;
__kernel void image_test(__read_only image2d_t image,__global unsigned char * data) 
{
    // current position
    const int2 pos = {get_global_id(0), get_global_id(1)};
    // value(here only one CL_A so .x is enough)
    unsigned char value=read_imageui(image, sampler_test, pos).x;
    // copy to data
    data[pos.x+pos.y*get_global_size(0)] = value;
}

///////////HOST main.cpp////////////////////////////

int main()
{
    //////////////////OpenCL Initialization////////////////////
    const char * filename  = "test.cl";
    cl_platform_id platform;
    cl_device_id device;
    cl_program program;
    cl_context context;
    cl_command_queue queue;

     ////////////////////OPENCL INITALIZATION IGNORED/////////////////
    int opencl_initial_result=CL_opencl_initial(filename,platform,device,program,
    context,queue);

    // 2014-8-6 23:23:48
    // Create kernel
    cl_kernel kernel_test=clCreateKernel( program, "image_test", NULL );

    // image format/////////????Is this step right???
    cl_image_format format;
    format.image_channel_order=CL_A;
    format.image_channel_data_type=CL_UNSIGNED_INT8;//  char????
    cl_int error_i;

    // Input image(gray, one channel)
    IplImage* image_input=cvLoadImage("d:\\image\\Bible.bmp",0);
    cvShowImage("gray",image_input);
    // image data
    unsigned char* image_data=(unsigned char*)image_input->imageData;

    int width=image_input->width;
    int height=image_input->height;

    // the image we use to show the result
    IplImage* image_show=cvCreateImage(cvSize(width,height),8,1);
    uchar* data_show=(uchar*)image_show->imageData;


    // opencl image
    cl_mem cl_image=clCreateImage2D(context,CL_MEM_READ_ONLY|CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR,&format,width,height,0,    (void*)image_data,&error_i);
    // opencl buffer
    cl_mem cl_buffer=clCreateBuffer(context,CL_MEM_READ_WRITE,width*height*sizeof(cl_uchar),NULL,NULL);

    size_t global_work_size[2] = {width, height};
    //size_t local_work_size[2]= {16,16};

    clSetKernelArg(kernel_test,0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&cl_image);
    clSetKernelArg(kernel_test,1, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&cl_buffer);

    clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(
        queue,
        kernel_test,
        2,
        NULL,
        global_work_size,
        NULL, 
        0,
        NULL,NULL);

     uchar* data_read = new uchar[width*height];
     clEnqueueReadBuffer(queue,
         cl_buffer,
         CL_TRUE,
         0,
         width*height*sizeof(cl_uchar),
         (void*)data_read,
         0,NULL,NULL);

     // copy the data to image
     for (int ii=0;ii<width;ii++)
    {
         for (int jj=0;jj<height;jj++)
         {
             data_show[jj*width+ii]=(uchar)data_read[jj*width+ii];
         }
     }

    cvShowImage("result",image_show);
    cvWaitKey();

////////////////////RELEASE DATA IGNORED/////////////////

    return 0;
};
```

Comment: just as a sidenote,- you probably should ditch the deprecated c-api IplImages in favour of cv::Mat

Comment: CL_UNSIGNED_INT8 is correct if you want 8 bit data.  Are you sure that the combination of CL_UNSIGNED_INT8 and CL_A is supported by your hardware?  The clGetSupportedImageFormats call will tell you.